# Execute any command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, go, terminal

I want a Go program to run a command (including built in commands) in the bash terminal as well as display it in the terminal itself like

```
$ls
trial.go output.txt hello.txt
$pwd
/home/bb/cc
$go run trial.go pwd
/home/bb/cc
$go run trial.go cd ..
$pwd
/home/bb
```

As, you can see, the golang script takes the command as input, and executes it in the same terminal and environment and also displays the output

I tried the below code but it does not work for the built-in commands

```
cmd := exec.Command("<the input command>")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
```

In simple words, the input string is going to be pasted in the terminal and is executed.

Comment: Bash built-in commands (unsurprisingly) only work when interpreted by bash. Try `exec.Command("bash -c 'the command'")`.

Comment: It is not possible to implement `go run trial.go cd ..` as you expect because a process cannot change the current working directory of an ancestor process.

Comment: `exec.Command` can be used to execute commands, that is, programs that are accessible in the filesystem via a path. Bash built-ins are not commands. They are not accessible via a path in the filesystem. They only exist with a running Bash process.

Comment: Aside from that, it sounds like a *horrible* idea to wrap a shell in Go. The only reason I can imagine is to emulate something like rsh or ssh - which would be reinventing the wheel, to put it polite.

Answer (score 1):

This works for 'one word' commands, maybe you can fix it to work with more words. Hope is useful.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"log"
"os/exec"
)

func main() {
    for {
    fmt.Println("Please introduce one word command (ls for example)")
    var command string
    fmt.Scan(&command)

    out, err := exec.Command(command).Output()
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Your output is: %s/n",out)
    }
 }
```